# Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): (ANGULAR)

Tags: css, angular

Estoy creando una barra de redes sociales y para eso utilizo *icomoon*. La había terminado y funcionaba perfecto. Ayer, mientras trabajaba en otro componente, ya no pude ver los íconos y ahora me aparece el siguiente problema:

> Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> C:...\src\app\header\header.component.css:66:12: Can't resolve './assets/fonts/icomoon.svg' in 'C:\Users...\src\app\header'

El mismo error ocurre en todas las líneas en las que incluyo las URL de los *fonts*.

Comment: tu fuente sigue en /assets/fonts/icomoon.svg ?

Comment: Al usar frameworks se reduce el control y ocurren cosas como estas.

Answer (score 0):

La razón de esto es porque a veces en Angular estas corriendo el compilador y el no te pone problema con alguna imagenes asi la ruta este mal. Sin embargo, cuando lo paras y lo vuelves a correr o corres un npm i antes ahí si te va a mostrar los errores. Lo más probable es que tengas mal las rutas de tus imágenes.

Trata en comentar la ruta que te da problema y ver si todo te compila bien, de ser así, lo que te recomiendo es que una vez comentada navegues por las carpetas hasta que encuentres el recurso que necesitas con la ruta correcta, en mi caso cuando me paso eso fue porque tenía la ruta mal.

```
&::before {
        left: 0;
        top: 350px;
        content: '';
        width: 350px;
        height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        animation: translateY 10s infinite linear;
        background: {
            image: url(../../../../assets/img/shape/pattern.png);
            // image: url(../../../../../assets/img/shape/pattern.png);
            position: center center;
            size: cover;
        };
    }
```